# How to get Ubuntu guest VM to recognize second VirtualBox monitor?

Tags: virtualbox, multiple-monitors, guest-os

Now that VirtualBox supports multiple monitors for guests, I decided to try it out with Ubuntu 11.04 Alpha3 (i386) as a guest.

Unfortunately, the second screen stays black and I can't even get `xrandr` to see the other display.

Is there some way of getting this feature to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figured out how to get it working - I had to install:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose-guest-x11
```

...and restart. The VM didn't boot the first time, but a hard reset seemed to sort things out.

**Note:** at first, Natty assumed I wanted to clone the displays... but a quick trip to `System->Preferences->Monitors` was able to fix that.

Comment: This package doesn't seem to be there in 13.04

Answer (score 2):

Multiple monitor setup of Virtual Box requires the installation of [Guest Additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/cant-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-for-ubuntu/22745#22745) in the guest OS.

Mostly depending on the graphic card there may still be some issues with Virtual Box and Compiz/Unity in 11.04. Make sure you download and run the most [recent version](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) of Virtual Box.

If Unity/Compiz still won't run you can try to run Ubuntu 11.04 in a multiple monitor setting by choosing *Ubuntu Classic Desktop (no effects)* on login.

Comment: What if I have the machine set to auto-login?

Comment: You can always turn off auto-login in *Find More Apps -> Installed -> see xx more results -> Users and Groups* at the password section.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: My fault: I was assuming you aready had installed Guest Additions (you need them for 3D/Unity anyway). It is best advice to use the most recent version of VBox and GA downloaded from Virtual Box.